# Magento Add New product event observer

Tags: events, magento

What is the event observer for new product added to the catalog by admin? I need to send a request when a new product added or updated. 
Is there an event observer available for that?

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
catalog_product_new_action

catalog_product_edit_action

catalog_product_prepare_save

catalog_controller_product_delete
```

More info refer [wiki magento event reference](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/magento_events)

Comment: Thanks, do you know where i can find the documentation for Magento events. I tried to search but i couldn't find anything but the list of  available events.

Comment: Check simple example here http://www.pierrefay.com/event-observers-magento-tutorial-howto-105

Comment: https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7/   you can found list of events here.

Answer (score 2):

You can Try :

```
<catalog_product_save_before>
        <observers>
            <yourmodule>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>yourmodule/observer</class>
                <method>catalog_product_save_before</method>
            </yourmodule>
        </observers>
    </catalog_product_save_before>

    <catalog_product_save_after>
        <observers>
            <yourmodule>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>yourmodule/observer</class>
                <method>catalog_product_save_after</method>
            </yourmodule>
        </observers>
    </catalog_product_save_after>
```

http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-event-observer-with-save-before-and-save-after/

Answer (score 0):

Try using `catalog_product_save_after`.